# Navigate from monthly to daily view in a dashboard

Tags: info-visualisation, data, dashboard, calendar, data-analysis

I need to provide users a way to view data on a dashboard on a monthly basis or daily basis. It should be possible to navigate back and forth from daily to monthly view.

The users should also be able to navigate directly into the days where there are data available, avoiding empty days.

What is a good navigation example for that?

Comment: This really depends on the device you're using and the platform, as well as the scope. Fixed app, website? Desktop/laptop, phone, cross-platform?

Comment: have you checked fullcalendar.io ? just a reference. might be what you wanted.

Comment: The primary objective for the dashboard is to visualize reports from a sensor network in the form of charts and indexes. The idea is that users shall have a different focus when looking at daily reports (main questions: how was my day? is there any significant variation?) or at monthly reports (main questions: which are my trends? are there interesting pattern emerging?). It should be a web application and it's ok to think mobile first.

Answer (score 2):

Google analytics app handles the navigation through dates and month in a well-organised manner. The dashboard of the app as shown in the first image has a data and two arrows on top of the screen. Which initially provides data on the date wise, when we click on the arrows it switches between the week, month and custom data which we have set already if any. By clicking on the date, the second screen opens where we can manage the data display settings.

This is one of the best data organising methods I have came across so far. A similar kind of design will do a better user experience.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just put a dropdown on the top of table from which user can select yearly monthly or daily for web applications.
[image]

For mobile apps you can get this done by gestures such as **pinch in** and **pinch out** - just as **google photos** or **google calendar**